# How can I match part of user input with innerText using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

**main.js**

```
const userInput = document.getElementById('user-text');
const placeholderText = document.getElementById('placeholder-text');

const placeholder = ['Fly', 'Cat'];
let pattern = '';

addTestText(placeholder);
const matchRegex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

userInput.addEventListener('input', e => addWords(e));

function addTestText(s) {

    for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        placeholderText.innerText += ` ${s[i]}`;
    }

    pattern = placeholderText.innerText; // pattern for regex
}

function addWords(e) {
    let text = e.target.innerText;
    
    console.log(matchRegex.test(text)); // when text matches a word in placeholder, then return true
}
```

**main.html**

```
<section class="words">
    <p id="placeholder-text" class="placeholder-text"></p>

    <p id='user-text' class="user-text" contenteditable="true"></p> /* Input from here */
</section>
```

Basically, lets say the pattern is 'Fly Cat', when the text matches 'Fly' it should return true, but for some reason the user has to correctly write the whole string in order for it to return true, what can I do? (and yes it has to be in order).

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you created is `Fly Cat`, which means *all* of these exact words. In order to match *either* of these words you'll need to use the `|` operator. `Fly|Cat`.

Here's your code with the new pattern.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById('user-text');
const placeholderText = document.getElementById('placeholder-text');

const placeholder = ['Fly', 'Cat'];
let pattern = '';

addTestText(placeholder);
const matchRegex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

userInput.addEventListener('input', e => addWords(e));

function addTestText(s) {
    // Since this is an array, I used join() instead of for loop.
    placeholderText.innerText = s.join(' ');
    // Pattern is created with the | operator.
    pattern = s.join('|');
}

function addWords(e) {
    let text = e.target.innerText;
    
    console.log(matchRegex.test(text)); // when text matches a word in placeholder, then return true
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="words">
    <p id="placeholder-text" class="placeholder-text"></p>

    <p id='user-text' class="user-text" contenteditable="true"></p> /* Input from here */
</section>
```